# How can I find a stored procedure on the basis of command or query used

Tags: sql

I want to get the stored procedure name on the basis of query (text) there around 400 to 500 stored procedures available in my db. Please provide help on this

Comment: ***WHAT*** db?? Please tag with the relevant database system you're using.

Comment: db as in general marc y do i need to specify it its sql this doesnt mean you down grade my point

Comment: SQL is just the **query language** - not a database. Stuff like this is often **vendor-specific**, so it matters whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2` or `sql-server` (or something else entirely) - that's why we need to know. And I **did NOT** downvote you ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database system you are talking about... but if its MS SQL then you can use below query

```
select * 
from databaseName.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Or you can use SQL Server Management Studio > expand the Database > Programmability > StoredProcedure > RightClick and Apply filters... Under filter you can enter the name or a word

Answer (score 0):

If it is Oracle following query will list all the procedure names:

```
column object_name format a30;
column procedure_name format a30;
column owner format a10;
select object_name, procedure_name, owner from all_procedures;
```